# No activity events when using the Java API

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

I'm using actviti with an implementation of `ActivitiEventListener`, which handles events such as `ACTIVTI_COMPLETED`/`TASK_CREATED` etc.

When communicating with process instances, I can see that the aforementioned events are fired (in `ACT_EVT_LOG` table), but when I do so via the Java API, no events are fired (e.g. when sending a message that a boundary event catches).

Below is a code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    readProperties();
    processEngine = buildProcessEngine();
    processEngine.getRuntimeService()
            .addEventListener(new ActivitiEventHandler("localhost", "61616"));
    new MessageSender(processEngine).sendMessage(args);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone would come across the same problem -

This was a misunderstanding: I presumed that all events would show up in the `ACT_EVT_LOG` table, not knowing that there's a registered event listener that popoulates it. After not seeing the expected events in the table I thought that activiti doesn't dispatch them, when in reality they were dispatched but had no indication.

So I added the following line, which made activiti populate `ACT_EVT_LOG`:

```
runtimeService.addEventListener(new EventLogger(processEngine.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getClock()));
```